# Android AsyncTask and Database call order of execution

Tags: android, database, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-volley

So I am running into an issue and I needed some help.

Just so you guys get a better idea of what my app is about, I'll write down what I would like my app to do.

1.Start GooglePlayServices and start getting the location of the user.
2.Once given the location, do a Volley request to a url and get some data and put it in JSONArray.
3.Take that JSONArray, and store its content inside the db,
4.Once that is all successful, show my viewPager adapter where I will have a listfragment and another fragment.

I tested my Volley request and it works, and I tried inserting it in the db so those two functions are working perfectly. I am trying to run a async task to do these two functions while displaying a ProgressDialog message saying "Fetching data...".

This is where I am running into trouble. When I fetch the total number of items in my db, it says 0 so I don't know whats going on. I think the postExecute is somehow running before my data even gets put in the db.

*I am not worrying about the case where the location is null right now so dont worry about it.

Problem: Not properly calling my retrieveFeed() (Volley Task) and insertToDB() calls properly within my AsyncTask.

I will post below my code and then I will post below the log statements as a reference to see whats happening.

```
import...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private BaseTabAdapter mAdapter;
    private JSONArray jsonArray;
    private JSONObject jsonObject;
    private List<Model> mList;
    private ProgressDialog mDialog;
    private DBHandler handler;
    boolean fetchedData = false;

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;

private Location mLastLocation;

// Google client to interact with Google API
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

// Location updates intervals in sec
private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    handler = new DBHandler(this);

    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // First we need to check availability of play services
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        // Building the GoogleApi client
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        createLocationRequest();

    }

}

/***
 * Initialize SlidingTabLayout
 */
private void initViews() {
    SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.tab_txt_layout, R.id.tab_name_txt);

    mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {

            return ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white);
        }
    });
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
}

/***
 * Starting a volley request to get JSON from URL
 */
private void retrieveFeed() {
    String url = "...json";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            // Get the JSONObject and JSONArray
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("...");

                // Insert values to database
                insertToDB();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cant fetch data right now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}

private void insertToDB() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            ... creating a new model and setting data parsed from the json

            // Inserting into DB
            handler.add(model...);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i("Finished", "inserting db");

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart:");
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: Connecting Google API Client");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume:");

    checkPlayServices();

    // Resuming the periodic location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop:");

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop: Disconnecting Google API Client");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause:");
    stopLocationUpdates();
}
/**
 * Creating google api client object
 * */
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.d(TAG, "buildGoogleApiClient:");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}

/**
 * Creating location request object
 * */
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    Log.d(TAG, "createLocationRequest:");
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
}

/**
 * Method to verify google play services on the device
 * */
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    Log.d(TAG, "checkPlayServices:");
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Starting the location updates
 * */
protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    Log.d(TAG, "startLocationUpdates:");
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    // Runnign the asyn task when i get a location, not worring about the case when if i dont get a location
    if (!fetchedData) {
        new FetchData().execute();
        fetchedData = true;
        Log.i("FetchData", "true");
    }

}

/**
 * Stopping location updates
 */
protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    Log.d(TAG, "stopLocationUpdates:");
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

/**
 * Google api callback methods
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected:");
    // Once connected with google api, get the location
    getLocation();
    startLocationUpdates();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended:");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged:");
    // Assign the new location
    mLastLocation = location;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()) + " - " +String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    getLocation();
}

private void getLocation() {
    Log.d(TAG, "displayLocation:");

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

}


private class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mDialog.setMessage("Fetching data...");
        mDialog.show();
        Log.i("onPreExecute", "started");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i("doInBackground", "started");
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            Log.i("mLastLocation", "notnull");
            retrieveFeed();
            Log.i("Finished", "retrieving feed");
        } else {
            Log.i("mLastLocation", "null");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("onPostExecute", "started");
        Log.i("COUNT", Integer.toString(handler.getTotalModels()));


        if (handler.getTotalModels() > 0) {
            Log.i("getTotalModels", "not zero");
            mAdapter = new BaseTabAdapter(MainActivity.this);
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            initViews();
        }

        mDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```

}

Logs:

```
D/MainActivity: checkPlayServices:
D/MainActivity: buildGoogleApiClient:
D/MainActivity: createLocationRequest:
D/MainActivity: onStart:
D/MainActivity: onStart: Connecting Google API Client
D/MainActivity: onResume:
D/MainActivity: checkPlayServices:
D/MainActivity: onConnected:
D/MainActivity: displayLocation:
D/MainActivity: startLocationUpdates:
I/onPreExecute: **started**
I/FetchRoadAsync: **true**
I/doInBackground: **started**
I/mLastLocation: **notnull**
I/Finished: **retrieving feed**
I/onPostExecute: **started**
I/COUNT: 0
I/Finished: **inserting db**
D/MainActivity: onLocationChanged:
D/MainActivity: displayLocation:
```

The asynctak is at the bottom and I call it from startLocationUpdates();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because Volley is already executing your request on another thread and is asynchronously calling you back in your callback methods on the main thread.  So there's no need to wrap the volley request in an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that. I fixed my mistake, your post helped me. I put the insertIntoDB into an async task and called that in onResponse method of the Volley Request. Thanks again